# Swift / App Store : Problem with in app purchase

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have a problem with my app. My in app purchase work very well on my side, on ios 12,4 iphone 5s. But when I send the binary at Apple Store I have a return :"We noticed that your app still still does not display the purchase button for the In-App Purchase product, in the app.".The buy button is only displayed when the processing to pay is ready. About 2 to 3 seconds at home. But with them apparently it does not work at all ...
Here is the full code for my store that handles everything. And I specify that with my iphone I manage to have the purchase window and to buy the integrated purchase in sandbox.

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit
import MessageUI

class ShopViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var buyBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var restore: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var mail: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var shopDescription: UILabel!
    
    var productsRequest = SKProductsRequest()
    var validProducts = [SKProduct]()
    var productIndex = 0
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         buyBtn.isHidden = true
              shopDescription.numberOfLines = 0
              shopDescription.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
              shopDescription.sizeToFit()
              shopDescription.text = NSLocalizedString("packpro", comment: "")
              //   SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
              let tap4 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(tappedMe5))
              mail.addGestureRecognizer(tap4)
              mail.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
              fetchAvailableProducts()
    }
    
     func fetchAvailableProducts()  {
            let productIdentifiers = NSSet(objects:
                "customLifePremium"        // 0
            )
            productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)
            productsRequest.delegate = self
            productsRequest.start()
        }
        
        func productsRequest (_ request:SKProductsRequest, didReceive response:SKProductsResponse) {
            if (response.products.count > 0) {
                validProducts = response.products
                let prod100coins = response.products[0] as SKProduct
                print("1st rpoduct: " + prod100coins.localizedDescription)
                buyBtn.isHidden = false
            }
        }
        
    /*    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, shouldAddStorePayment payment: SKPayment, for product: SKProduct) -> Bool {
            return true
        }*/
        
        func canMakePurchases() -> Bool {  return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()  }
        
        func purchaseMyProduct(_ product: SKProduct) {
            if self.canMakePurchases() {
                let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
                SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
                SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
            } else { print("Purchases are disabled in your device!") }
        }
        
        func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
            for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
                if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction {
                    switch trans.transactionState {
                        
                    case .purchased:
                        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "premiumUser")
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "limitedVersion")
                        break
                        
                    case .failed:
                        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                        print("Payment has failed.")
                        break
                    case .restored:
                        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                        print("Purchase has been successfully restored!")
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "premiumUser")
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "limitedVersion")
                        break
                        
                    default: break
                    }}}
        }
        
        func restorePurchase() {
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self as SKPaymentTransactionObserver)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
        }
        
        func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
            print("The Payment was successfull!")
        }
        
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            setGradientBackground()
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        }
        
        @IBAction func restoreCC(_ sender: Any) {
            restorePurchase()
        }
        
        @IBAction func buyCC(_ sender: Any) {
            productIndex = 0
            purchaseMyProduct(validProducts[productIndex])
        }
    
        @objc func tappedMe5()
        {
            if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
                let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
                mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
                mail.setToRecipients(["dfmv.enterprise@gmail.com"])
                mail.setSubject("")
                mail.setMessageBody("", isHTML: true)
                present(mail, animated: true)
            }else{
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("info", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("noClientMail", comment: ""), preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("ok", comment: ""), style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        
        func setGradientBackground() {
            let colorTop =  UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.30, blue:0.30, alpha:1.0).cgColor
            let colorBottom = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.69, blue:0.25, alpha:1.0).cgColor
            
            let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
            gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
            gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
            
            self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Gist that I personally used a week ago and passed the AppStore review for In-App Purchase flow.

**IAP** Service in **Swift 5**:

https://gist.github.com/egzonpllana/abd6d385bb45b1e329fe85a624ee531f

You can call `IAPService.shared.getProducts()` in AppDelegate method: `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to have all the products ready to use from your StoreKit in any viewcontroller, just check `IAPService.shared.products.count`.

Or call in your specific viewcontroller inside viewDidLoad and listen to changes with: `IAPService.shared.didFinishRetrievingProducts = { [ weak self ] in ... }`

Comment: Thank you so much, i will check that